# mod_rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, debian

I'm new to server administration but I was able to get a LAMP setup running on my new VPS.  I uploaded a few web files that work on my other server, but they seem to give me the error: "File does not exist" in my /var/log/apache2/error.log file.  The homepage loads just fine through my scripting, but other pages don't.

.htaccess file code

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have enabled mod_rewrite on the server and can see it running under my phpinfo() page I have created.  Simply don't know why this issue is happening.  If I need to post anything else, please let me know :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It looks like your site or virtual host has not been granted the appropriate permissions to process `.htaccess` files. You can test it easily by making a syntax error on purpose: if your site does not crash, the file is being ignored.

Try something like this in your main `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/site">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

... or this (to your liking):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowOverride All
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Where can I find my main httpd.conf file?

Comment: In my situation, I needed to add `AllowOverride all` to `apache.conf` under `<Directory /var/www/>`.

Comment: I had different issue. mod_rewrite wasn't enabled for my apache. Just to help someone who might be looking a solution. Take a look at this link http://xmodulo.com/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-on-debian-ubuntu.html

Comment: When a given a module is not installed or enabled you get a clear message in your error log: *Invalid command 'Foo', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

Comment: Where is the httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 11):

When I had this problem it turned out that the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` had the `AllowOverride All`, but the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` also had the same entry for our web `Directory` with `AllowOverwrite None`. So be sure to check both places!

Comment: Thank you! Love you! You solved my problem <3 I hate this kind of config files :D

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: Module rewrite does not exist
February 21, 2014 by Sharad Chhetri Leave a Comment

While working on Apache Module in Ubuntu,I found rewrite problem in Apache Web Server.I tried to enable the rewrite module but got this error ERROR: Module rewrite does not exist!.After troubleshooting,I found the problem was with mod_rewrite module.

After doing some more troubleshooting,it is found that the rewrite.load file was missing in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ .

Now,I checked the mod_rewrite.so actual module file and Wow it was there.

Below given is step by step command which I ran,to solve this issue.Here is the reference from my system

root@tuxworld:~# a2enmod rewrite

ERROR: Module rewrite does not exist!

root@tuxworld:~# ls -l /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58728 May 28  2020 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

root@tuxworld:~#

root@tuxworld:~# echo "LoadModule rewrite_module

/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load

root@tuxworld:~#

root@tuxworld:~# a2enmod rewriteEnabling module rewrite.

To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

service apache2 restart

root@tuxworld:~#

After this I restarted the apache2 service

sudo service apache2 restart